# How to change data-content of popover according to boolean value?

Tags: jquery, html, typescript

HTML:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
  });
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-left" 
 (click)="showNotifications()"data-toggle="popover" title="Status"  data- 
 content="Success" data-trigger="hover">Notifications
</button> 


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  private status: string;
  private success: boolean = true;
  showNotifications() {
    if (this.success = !this.success) {
      return status = 'Success';
    } else return status = 'Failed';
  }
}
```

I want this data-content="success" to change to "failed" if in shownotification function status value is false and success if it is true.Can anyone tell how it can be done?

Comment: Hi @sana ejaz, will you include the html of "popover" and showNotifications() function? Thanks.

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 private status:string ;
private success:boolean=true;
  showNotifications()
  {
  
 if(this.success=!this.success)
 {
   return status='Success';

 }
 else
 return status ='Failed';
  }}

Comment: button is the html code of popover

Comment: Can anyone help?